# Non-optimal program, bad choice of language or Low-speed system?

Tags: program-optimization

To check some results of an article, I wrote the proposed algorithm from the Coding articles. In the article, some results from the algorithm were obtained. Unfortunately, the performance of my program was very different from what was said in the article.

In the article, results were obtained in 20min but I got quarter of them in 5h. Plus, in article algorithm was written in Matlab and I wrote in Python. In addition, the author mentioned that their system is a desktop computer with 2.4-GHz CPU and 8-GB RAM, but mine is a laptop with 2.13 GHz CPU and 2-GB RAM (Pentium(R)).

Now, which one do you think is the real problem for slow-performance of my program?

1-The non-optimal program that I wrote?

2-Bad choice of language (Python vs. Matlab)?

3-Low-speed system compare to the system of the author?

Comment: Without any further details, any 3 of them is a possibility. In fact with more details, I'd still have to _guess_ what option might have more impact. If you have taken different inputs, than in the paper, that's a possibility as well. I think the only way to answer this question conclusively is to ask the author of the paper for the implementation. That way, you can at least see whether 3 applies. All this is of course under the assumption that the author of the article is honest about the results.

Comment: @Discretelizard Base on information in the article, I took the same inputs as the author. Actually, my outputs were same too. But the problem was at the time of the run.